# Can I tell GitHub (or eq.) to use ASCII to make my binary files readable?

Tags: github, ascii, binaryfiles

I want to host a binary file on a web-based hosting service for git (i.e. GitHub) so I can easily see any changes made to it.

The binary file in question uses the common ASCII character encoding so that this binary

```
73 63 6F 70 65 20 68 75 72 72 72 20 69 6E 69 74 69 61 6C 69 7A 65 72 20 64 65 72 70 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 66 75 6E 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 64 65 72 70 20 74 61 6B 65 73 20 6E 6F 74 68 69 6E 67 20 72 65 74 75 72 6E 73 20 6E 6F 74 68 69 6E 67 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 63 61 6C 6C 20 53 65 74 53 74 61 72 74 4C 6F 63 50 72 69 6F 28 24 42 2C 24 41 2C 24 41 2C 4D 41 50 5F 4C 4F 43 5F 50 52 49 4F 5F 48 49 47 48 29 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 65 6E 64 66 75 6E 63 74 69 6F 6E 0D 0A 65 6E 64 73 63 6F 70 65
```

becomes this readable text (†)

```
scope hurrr initializer derp
    function derp takes nothing returns nothing
        call SetStartLocPrio($B,$A,$A,MAP_LOC_PRIO_HIGH)
    endfunction
endscope
```

The problem is that services like GitHub will only show me the raw binary when I want to view the file in-browser (or have me download and open it in a text editor):

[image: GitHub's view of binary files]

Right now, to have any changes made, I have to download the changed binary file, convert it to readable text, then use `diff` to see what changes have been made. This is tedious and loses the beautiful web interface that GitHub has.

So my question is this: **Can I tell GitHub (or any equivalent service) to translate a binary file to readable text?**

--

(†) For anyone interested in trivia, this is indeed [vJass](http://www.wc3c.net/vexorian/jasshelpermanual.html) syntax for WarCraft III.

Comment: Did you try with a `.gitattributes` file ? You may want to start with that: `*.ext text`. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: So, your binary file contains (ASCII-)encoded characters only? Isn't that the definition of a text file? What do you mean by "convert it to readable text", since it's *already* readable text? What is the extension of the file? What does it actually contain?

Comment: @NoDataFound Thank you, I did not know about .gitattributes. After reading some of the documentation you linked, I tried adding a simple .gitattribute file `*.wct -text -diff`, but GitHub still only recognizes my .wct file as binary.

@JBNizet The file format is .wct and contains only ASCII-encoded characters as far as I know. However, GitHub and any text editor I use does not recognize it as a text file.

Comment: Try the diff option. Don't know if it work in github but this answer seem to indicate it works in git: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24381671/1023553 See also Linguist: https://github.com/github/linguist

Comment: What does a text editor show when you open it then? And how do you convert it to text?

Comment: @NoDataFound Thank you. It seems changing .gitattributes to `*.wct diff` makes the `$ git diff` command interpret the .wct file as text. It does not work for GitHub however. Do you know of any web-based git hosting service like GitHub that it works for? @JBNizet The two code blocks I used in my question post are what my .wct file shows up as in a text editor and what it looks like after conversion to ASCII respectively.

Comment: I found this very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212291/make-github-use-gitattributes-binary-attribute Quote: "So, for now Github does not support .gitattributes file to suppress any diff." I guess what I want is not possible for GitHub.

Comment: @Mossmyr: play with the linguist from github. As far as I understand it, it is what handle how github determine binary files.