# Why github/gitlab are appling gitattributes incorrectly?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitattributes

This is a similar issue I found: [Make github use .gitattributes "binary" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212291/make-github-use-gitattributes-binary-attribute)
If it's not intended to work in Github then my question applies to Gitlab only.

---

So the question: Imagine creating a branch with a single text `Dockerfile` and following `.gitattributes`:

```
[core]
    whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab
[apply]
    whitespace=fix
* binary
Dockerfile text=auto diff merge
```

You push this code, you can view commit in interface and it works just fine.
Then you decide that `Dockerfile` should be binary as well (for whatever reason) and remove the last line. You commit it and then make change to the `Dockerfile` to check if it works. You call `git show` and it shows that changes indeed applied:

```
pzixe@ZPC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Repos/gitlab-test (all-binary)
$ git show HEAD
commit 141451116e292ae30a515920e6efb906f84b4142 (HEAD -> all-binary, origin/all-binary, github/all-binary)
Author: Psilon <pzixel@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 14 19:25:04 2021 +0300

    test changes

diff --git a/Dockerfile b/Dockerfile
index 11f0f66..fef4bc1 100644
Binary files a/Dockerfile and b/Dockerfile differ
```

But now if you check the github interface you will see that it actually shows a text diff instead of binary diff which was asked:

[image]

Then you're trying to see if GitLab is working differently and find out it's not:

[image]

So the question is: is there any way to make this working? I'd expect to see a text diff of initial commit `6c0745e` and binary collapsed diff on latest commit `1414511`

Here is a repo with reproduced case: https://github.com/Pzixel/test-gitlab

Comment: Are the first four lines in your config or in your `.gitattibutes` file?

Comment: It's all `gitattribute` as you can see in linked repo

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitattributes` file has invalid syntax and is probably being completely ignored on that basis.  The first four lines (reproduced below) are configuration syntax and can't be included in a `.gitattributes` file.  Configuration cannot be shipped as part of the repository and would need to either be stored in `.git/config` or in your personal `.gitconfig`.

```
[core]
    whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab
[apply]
    whitespace=fix
```

Beyond that, as [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212291/make-github-use-gitattributes-binary-attribute), GitHub doesn't use the `binary` attribute in `.gitattributes` to determine which files should be diffed.  It will diff those files which appear to be plain text (and, by default, not autogenerated) and will not diff files which appear to be binary.  You can mark a file as `linguist-generated` to indicate that it's a generated file, though.

I don't know if GitLab does or doesn't support this feature, but given that your `.gitattributes` file contains invalid syntax, that's probably not helping.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right. This paragraph made me think that I actually can ship it: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion . You linked answer is what I've referenced in my question as well, so I've seen it but things could change in last 7 years. Thanks for reply I'l double check if gitattributes doesn't supprot this but I'm pretty sure that I recall this working even if it's not documented

Comment: I've just checked with valid  `.gitattributes` file - it didn't work. Github just don't use `.gitattributes` but gitlab should (according to the docs). Going to ask there then. Thanks